# Import mysql database remotely without using files

Tags: mysql, replication

I am trying to set up a replication slave.

I was hoping if I set the binlog position to 0 on the slave it would just start reading from 0 and replicate everything from scratch until it matched the master, but the slave's not doing anything, and not giving errors either.

So I first need a current database snapshot. Can I do this without dumping the database into a file if both servers can talk to each other on the local network? I tried this command but it just spits out the usage help:

`slave ~$ sudo mysqlimport --host='[master-server-ip]' --user='repl' -pC`

To reiterate, I want to transfer all databases (except the mysql built in databases) over the network without having to manually transfer files.

Comment: This might help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers

Comment: @AmirSaleem sadly not because it uses files and manual file transfering. I know you can do it that way, but I want to do it more streamlined.

Comment: I've posted a possible answer but anyway why don't you want to transfer the DB using files? Is it because master DB is constantly updated? For this exact case there is Percona XtraBackup tool which can make backups of hot DBs and after import you can easily configure replication without missing anything.

Comment: @Stalinko in part because it's just tedious, in other part because in the production environment I have to jump through guard nodes, so I have to scp, rm, scp, rm, scp, rm ad inifitum. Also, how come mariadb can transfer data to remote clients, but you can't use that functionality to make an immediate backup?

Comment: @USB_S0lderer normally replication isn't supposed to be used for full data transfer. On live DBs there are only binlogs for few last days, not all time, hence full data transfer isn't possible. Also such way of transfer is excessive because you not simply copy the data but repeat ALL of queries which generated that data. If you can't store the backup on your master server you can dump it directly into the slave server. Or you can dump master onto your computer, then upload that backup onto slave. It's simple and no headache with tricky replications.

Comment: @Stalinko makes sense, but I still have to copy to and from the guard node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 0 as binlog position but you also have to specify the log file.

You can see the name of the first binlog file in your MySQL data directory (usually `/var/lib/mysql` on unix).

Then try something like this on the slave server:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO
    MASTER_HOST='...',
    MASTER_PORT=3306,
    MASTER_USER='...',
    MASTER_PASSWORD='...',
    MASTER_LOG_FILE='<your first binlog file>',
    MASTER_LOG_POS=0;
START SLAVE;
```

Of course that will work if all binlogs are still present on the master server since it has been created which might be not your case since binlogs are automatically cleaned after some time.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the first logs are still in fact present. However, filling in the command and executing it gives me `ERROR 1201 (HY000): Could not initialize master info structure for ''; more error messages can be found in the MariaDB error log`, and no actual entry in the error log. Any idea what could be causing this, and should I file a bug report to mariadb?

Comment: @USB_S0lderer Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933590/2244262